# How do I re-export a symbol from a crate via FFI with a different name?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a crate, `ffizz-string`, which has a number of public functions with an `fz_string_` prefix.   In another crate `taskchampion-lib`, I would like to export these same functions, but with a different prefix (`tc_string_`).  The idea here is that `ffizz-string` provides some generic FFI string utilities, and the crate using those utilities wants to "rebrand" the functions to match the  crate's other FFI functions.

For Rust libraries, this renaming is easy: `pub use fz_string_borrow as tc_string_borrow`.  However, this does not seem to do the trick for exported functions.  I have a few things I've tried below, and for each I looked at the resulting symbols using `nm ./target/debug/deps/libtaskchampion_lib-....rlib | grep string_borrow

```
#![allow(non_upper_case_globals)]

// attempt 0: demonstrate that regular function symbols appear in the nm grep
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn tc_string_borrow_0() {
    todo!()
}
// result: appears in nm grep as 'tc_string_borrow_0`:
// 0000000000000000 T tc_string_borrow_0

// attempt 1: just rename using 'as'
pub use ffizz_string::fz_string_borrow as tc_string_borrow_1;
// result: appears in nm grep as 'fz_string_borrow`

// attempt 2:  rename with `link_name`
// link_name only applies to foreign fns and statics
extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "tc_string_borrow_2"]
    pub static tc_string_borrow_2:
        unsafe extern "C" fn(cstr: *const i8) -> ffizz_string::fz_string_t;
}
// result: not renamed (turns out link_name was the wrong attribute)

// attempt 3: export_name on a fn
/*
// "attribute should be applied to a free function, impl method or static"
#[export_name="tc_string_borrow_3"]
pub use ffizz_string::fz_string_borrow as tc_string_borrow_3;
*/
// result: error: attribute should be applied to a free function, impl method or static

// attempt 4: export_name on a static
#[export_name = "tc_string_borrow_4"]
pub static tc_string_borrow_4: unsafe extern "C" fn(cstr: *const i8) -> ffizz_string::fz_string_t =
    ffizz_string::fz_string_borrow;
// result: compiles, but tc_string_borrow_4 is a pointer to fz_string_borrow:
// 0000000000000000 D tc_string_borrow_4
 
// attempt 5: export_name on a static
#[used]
pub static tc_string_borrow_5: unsafe extern "C" fn(cstr: *const i8) -> ffizz_string::fz_string_t =
    ffizz_string::fz_string_borrow;
// result: not renamed
```

The one approach that I've found effective is to wrap the utility functions with another function:

```
#[inline]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn tc_string_borrow(cstr: *const i8) -> ffizz_string::fz_string_t {
    ffizz_string::fz_string_borrow(cstr)
}
```

But this relies on the compiler to inline those cross-crate calls, and also requires reiterating the function signature. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does it not work when it is a pointer?

Comment: It doesn't -- calling e.g., `tc_string_borrow("hello world")` from C will segfault.  I suspect that declaring the value as a pointer would work, although I haven't tried that.  I think the syntax would be `fz_string_t (*tc_string_borrow)(char *);`

Comment: (also, that would make this an indirect jump, which is less efficient than just calling the function directly)